# Are you able to edit an XML file via the app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am making a "contact book" for my work.
What I need to do is being able to add and remove contacts as you like, but I have no idea if this is possible when I have the contacts in an xml file.

Are you even able to, got any tip what other solution I can use?

Comment: Where is your XML file stored ? Yes you can modify XML files, or otherwise save your data in an Sqlite database.

Comment: You can, but I'd stay away from XML and use SQL or JSON

Comment: Yeah I thought SQLite would be a good way too!